# Python loading multiple Json file with Chinese characters

Tags: python, json, datatable

I have below like Multiple Json file (test.json):

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5886dff9129a960d825fd574"},"game_type":6,"desk_id":41387,"round_count":2,"begin_time":{"$date":"2017-01-24T04:58:50.475Z"},"end_time":{"$date":"2017-01-24T05:02:33.959Z"},"club_id":11006,"club_name":"梧州麻将新手圈","owner_nick_name":"牌乐门","create_time":{"$date":"2017-01-24T05:02:49.860Z"},"items":[{"uid":16252,"nickname":"林家斌","win_gold":-4},{"uid":100074706,"nickname":" 年青*战场","win_gold":-4},{"uid":100175661,"nickname":" 所谓","win_gold":12},{"uid":100038017,"nickname":" 暖心","win_gold":-4}],"reason":"玩家退出房间，游戏结算","ok":true}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5886e996129a960d825fdf05"},"game_type":6,"desk_id":38913,"round_count":1,"begin_time":{"$date":"2017-01-24T05:41:26.135Z"},"end_time":{"$date":"2017-01-24T05:43:04.019Z"},"club_id":11006,"club_name":"梧州麻将新手圈","owner_nick_name":"牌乐门","create_time":{"$date":"2017-01-24T05:43:50.020Z"},"items":[{"uid":12028,"nickname":"林2--","win_gold":-2},{"uid":100080735,"nickname":" 圣裔","win_gold":6},{"uid":100087488,"nickname":" 平静","win_gold":-2},{"uid":100017168,"nickname":" 陈颖","win_gold":-2}],"reason":"玩家退出房间，游戏结算","ok":true}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5886ea68129a960d825fe04a"},"game_type":6,"desk_id":40381,"round_count":1,"begin_time":{"$date":"2017-01-24T05:45:40.833Z"},"end_time":{"$date":"2017-01-24T05:47:01.694Z"},"club_id":11006,"club_name":"梧州麻将新手圈","owner_nick_name":"牌乐门","create_time":{"$date":"2017-01-24T05:47:20.723Z"},"items":[{"uid":11987,"nickname":"转转","win_gold":-2},{"uid":100185361,"nickname":" 妞妞儿","win_gold":6},{"uid":100070056,"nickname":" 草木虫","win_gold":-2},{"uid":100195039,"nickname":" 三姑娘","win_gold":-2}],"reason":"玩家退出房间，游戏结算","ok":true}
```

I have tried below:

```
pd.concat([json_normalize(json.loads(line)) for line in open('test.json')])
```

but got below error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 pd.concat([json_normalize(json.loads(line)) for line in open('test.json')])
>
> c:\winpython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\json__init__.pyc
>   in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int,
>   parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
>       336             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
>       337             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
>   --> 338         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>       339     if cls is None:
>       340         cls = JSONDecoder
>
> c:\winpython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\json\decoder.pyc
>   in decode(self, s, _w)
>       364 
>       365         """
>   --> 366         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>       367         end = _w(s, end).end()
>       368         if end != len(s):
>
> c:\winpython-64bit-2.7.10.2\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\json\decoder.pyc
>   in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
>       380         """
>       381         try:
>   --> 382             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
>       383         except StopIteration:
>       384             raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 2:
>   invalid start byte

and also tried something like below:

```
import codecs
temp = []
with codecs.open('test.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('\n','')
        temp.append(line)
map(json.loads,temp)
```

Got the same error.

But for single Json like this:

```
json_normalize(json.loads('{"_id":{"$oid":"5886dff9129a960d825fd574"},"game_type":6,"desk_id":41387,"round_count":2,"begin_time":{"$date":"2017-01-24T04:58:50.475Z"},"end_time":{"$date":"2017-01-24T05:02:33.959Z"},"club_id":11006,"club_name":"梧州麻将新手圈","owner_nick_name":"牌乐门","create_time":{"$date":"2017-01-24T05:02:49.860Z"},"items":[{"uid":16252,"nickname":"林家斌","win_gold":-4},{"uid":100074706,"nickname":" 年青*战场","win_gold":-4},{"uid":100175661,"nickname":" 所谓","win_gold":12},{"uid":100038017,"nickname":" 暖心","win_gold":-4}],"reason":"玩家退出房间，游戏结算","ok":true}'))
```

So got what table I want to:

[image]

I want to get all tables concatenated with one big table like above table.
What is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on WinPython-3.6, if you registered your file with notepad as 'UTF-8', this may work.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
pd.concat([json_normalize(json.loads(line)) for line in open('test.json', encoding="utf-8-sig")])





    _id.$oid    begin_time.$date    club_id club_name   create_time.$date   desk_id end_time.$date  game_type   items   ok  owner_nick_name reason  round_count
0   5886dff9129a960d825fd574    2017-01-24T04:58:50.475Z    11006   梧州麻将新手圈 2017-01-24T05:02:49.860Z    41387   2017-01-24T05:02:33.959Z    6   [{'uid': 16252, 'nickname': '林家斌', 'win_gold':...   True    牌乐门 玩家退出房间，游戏结算 2
0   5886e996129a960d825fdf05    2017-01-24T05:41:26.135Z    11006   梧州麻将新手圈 2017-01-24T05:43:50.020Z    38913   2017-01-24T05:43:04.019Z    6   [{'uid': 12028, 'nickname': '林2--', 'win_gold'...   True    牌乐门 玩家退出房间，游戏结算 1
0   5886ea68129a960d825fe04a    2017-01-24T05:45:40.833Z    11006   梧州麻将新手圈 2017-01-24T05:47:20.723Z    40381   2017-01-24T05:47:01.694Z    6   [{'uid': 11987, 'nickname': '转转', 'win_gold': ...   True    牌乐门 玩家退出房间，游戏结算 1
```

​

Comment: Oh That is really a very good news,thanks so much for your information.